# Is there a pattern I can use to edit dropdown lists in an MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am looking for a general, reusable UI pattern I can use for editing the content of dropdown lists in my MVC3 app. That is, some of the Id-Name pairs used to populate dropdowns for edit views exist only for this purpose, and have no dedicated controller-view setup themselves. E.g. Industry and Sector for course modules. Each list is only an Id-Name structure, but Sector has an IndustryId value as well.

Now I really don't want to use the standard scaffolded views for these, i.e. create,edit, and list with links, but I can't help wondering how best to improve on these. Should I bind each list to an editor that just renders a an EditorFor textbox for each item in the list, with jQuery to add a new item or delete an item? is there some established way of doing this?

**NOTE:** This is not about loading a dropdown list. It's about loading the values for a dropdown list into a view for editing them, to control what appears in the dropdown list when it loads by whatever means.

Comment: take a look at the AjaxDropdown from http://awesome.codeplex.com you write the code to populate it just once in a controller that is used just for it, and after you can declare it any view you want without having to pass data to it from the controller of that view

Comment: See my blog blog Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx ) and Working with the DropDownList Box and jQuery (http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc )

Comment: This may not be exactly what you are looking for, but what I've done in the past is populate a [jQueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) box with the distinct values for a column in the database, but allow for the autocomplete to accept new values.  That way you don't actually have to maintain a list of potential values outside of the actual ones in use.  I don't know that there is any sort of "accepted pattern" for this though, probably best rolling the one that makes the most sense for your user's workflow.

Comment: how will this work for you http://coffeescripter.com/code/editable-select/

Comment: So you're looking for something to edit any database table, provided it has the right id/name structure?

Comment: @Dave, pretty much. I use an model called DropDownItemListModel, so I'm basically looking for a nice way to edit that model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a pattern per se, but we deal with this sort of thing as well (dozens of lookup tables with the same structure) and we use simple pages with a jqGrid. The editing is live in the sense that changing a row causes an Ajax call to the controller to modify the lookup value itself. Works fairly well. We ended up having a dedicated view for each of the editable lookup tables (not all of them are) but it would have been simple enough to use the same view, controller and client-side script for all of them.

Comment: Yes, I think simply using a grid will probably be best, although I will look at the [Kendo UI](http://www.kendoui.com/web.aspx) grid before jqGrid.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery, and jQuery UI to customise your dropDown lists